# How to send data on a telephone line to ISO8583 host (Dial up NAC), the client is in JAVA?

Tags: java, iso8583

I am building an ISO8583 client written in java, i need to send to ISO8583 host which is hosted on a NAC with a dedicated phone number (Analog).

THe client(PC) is generating TCP/IP data , it should ideally call the phone number and send the data packets and receive the reponse data packets.

I am done with all the Iso8583 parts and also it works with IP->IP, 
I want to know how to setup it to work in IP(TCP) -> Analog Phone line (HOST).

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 3):

If you are using NAC, then you don't need to TCP -> Serial line, that is job of the NAC switch unless you are writing your own switch.

The transaction flow goes ISO HOST -> NAC (TCP)-> NAC (Serial) -> Terminal/POS.

If you want to send serial packets from the PC to the NAC then you need to connect one modem to serial port of the PC and send the data across.

If you have a third party NAC (Ingenico,Verifone) then you don't need modem as they usually give a serial interface that you could connect with PC to send the data.

If you are interested in C APIs (you can easily convert them into java), please checkout the github project

https://github.com/kchandan/nac_switch

I would suggest you to fork it and create JAVA APIs that might be useful to others.

Comment: I am not using third party NAC, just using a 56k usb analog modem,
yes i want to send serial packets from PC to NAC, i am able to connect to host via the modem using the "ATDXXXXX" command.

So after connected, need to send and test any ISO 8583 message,
say 0800 test connection message.
example 0800 message starting with TPDU header
600001000008002000010000C0000099000000013530303030303035303030303237303038303838303135
Is it enough if we just send the data bytes as it is using the Write() method of the serial port outputstream in java ? 
How to set modem to data mode, AT commands to send data?